# Quaternion rotation to latitude/longitude

Tags: c++, opengl, quaternions, glm-math

**TL;DR**
I have a quaternion representing the orientation of a sphere (an Earth globe). From the quaternion I wish to derive a latitude/longitude. I can visualize in my mind the process, but am weak with the math (matrices/quaternions) and not much better with the code (still learning OpenGL/GLM). How can I achieve this? This is for use in OpenGL using c++ and the GLM library.

**Long Version**
I am making a mapping program based on a globe of the Earth - not unlike Google Earth, but for a customized purpose that GE cannot be adapted to.

I'm doing this in C++ using OpenGL with the GLM library.

I have successfully coded the sphere and am using a quaternion directly to represent it's orientation. No Euler angles involved. I can rotate the globe using mouse motions thus rotating the globe on arbitrary axes depending on the current viewpoint and orientation.

However, I would like to get a latitude and longitude of a point on the sphere, not only for the user, but for some internal program use as well.

I can visualize that this MUST be possible. Imagine a sphere in world space with no rotations applied. Assuming OpenGL's right hand rule, the north pole points up the Y axis with the equator parallel on the X/Z plane. The latitude/longitude up the Y axis is thus 90N and something else E/W (degenerate). The prime meridian would be on the +Z axis.

If the globe/sphere is rotated arbitrarily the globe's north pole is now somewhere else. This point can be mapped to a latitude/longitude of the original sphere before rotation. Imagine two overlaying spheres, one the globe which is rotated, and the other a fixed reference.

(Actually, it would be in reverse. The latitude/longitude I seek is the point on the rotated sphere that correlates to the north pole of the unrotated reference sphere)

In my mind it seems that somehow I should be able to get the vector of the Earth globe's orientation axis from it's quaternion and compare it to that of the unrotated sphere. But I just can't seem to grok how to do that. (I guess I still don't fully understand mats and quats and have only blundered into my success so far)

I'm hoping to achieve this without needing a crash course in the deep math. I'm looking for a solution/understanding/guidance from the point of view of being able to use the GLM library to achieve my goal. Ideally a code sample with some general explanation. I learn best from example.

FYI, in my code the rotation of the globe/sphere is totally independent of the camera (which does use Euler angles) so it can be moved independently. So I can't use anything from the camera to determine this.

Comment: Can you imagine the volume of spam that SO would get if you didn't require reputation to post a picture?

Comment: @genpfault, I would have asked this privately, but apparently there is no private message system. As a new user, I'd like an explanation for the edit of my post. Was the deleted content a violation of some rule? If so, could you point me directly to said rule and exactly how I violated it? Surely a one-line jesting quip of criticism about the unexpected discovery of the need for 'reputation' to post an image hardly warrants summary deletion of said content? I don't see how what I said is of any harm. Please help me to avoid getting a bad first impression of my use of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @genpfault - I just noticed even my introduction pointing out that I am a new user here was deleted. "New user, first post." Why? That was put there so readers (like you) would know I'm new here and if I did something wrong hopefully they (like you) would be understanding and politely correct me. But if wonton edits of posts and comments are the norm here, that would explain my confusion on other postings and replies I've read, when I see replies that have no context or they're to other replies I can't even find. Now I DO have a bad impression of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Just [general](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/150045) noise [reduction](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778).

Comment: Saying 'hi' is noise? Sorry, but this is just plain silly. However, I shall endeavor to construct my future writings in a completely inhuman emotionless and dry Vulcan-like manner in the future.

Comment: Additionally, perhaps this information should be added to the introductory tour page. I read that and the TOS before signing up, so that explains some of my reaction. This has taken me completely by surprise. It's like buying a car only to learn after signing the check that it doesn't come with a gas tank. Sorry for the rant. I'll leave it at this. But I just can't stop laughing at how stupid silly this is, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to follow that link (ie. use boost ;) ) from that thread [Longitude / Latitude to quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437865/longitude-latitude-to-quaternion) and then deduct the inverse of that conversion.
Or you could also go add a step by converting your quaternion into Euler angle?